# Permanently disable second screen

Tags: linux, laptop, multiple-monitors, xorg

My laptop's monitor does not work any more and thus I've attached an external monitor.

On boot, GDM still recognizes the primary laptop screen and displays it's login window on it. Which I then can't see.

I can disable the laptop's screen by running `xrandr --output LVDS1 --off` after logging in.
I tried putting this command into `~\.xinitrc` and into a `./40-xrandr.sh` in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d`.

Both to no effect at all. I had hoped that it'd at least would switch off the laptop's screen on log in.

**How do I disable the laptop's screen *before* GDM starts?**

Comment: The BIOS might have an option to set the default monitor. A lot of the modern laptop BIOSes have this. Check your BIOS manual. When set correctly and your second monitor is plugged in, the BIOS will treat it as the primary (your OS will think this is the main screen), otherwise it will fall back to the laptop screen.

Comment: I looked for it, but the BIOS does not provide such an option.

Comment: No BIOS setting with the options like _Internal LCD_ and _External_? Well, I'm sorry then. It would have been the simplest solution.

Comment: Yes, I know. I hoped for that too. And it's even a 'business system' (Dell Latitude D830) ...

Comment: Does [this](http://i31.photobucket.com/albums/c371/direraptor22/100_0517_zps2130481d.jpg) match your BIOS screen? I see a **Video** option on the left. It appears to have sub-options (as indicated by the `+`). What are the options available under **Video**? There are so much variations in BIOSes that one can't pinpoint exactly what option to use unless one looks at it. And the terminologies/descriptions used by the manufacturer are quite often inadequate, confusing or misleading.

Comment: Yes it does, but there's no option under Video that allows for disabling monitors. Pretty dull, IMHO. Thanks for you patience!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This makes linux ignore the LVDS output altogether. That way it will not be used by all login managers, and won't appear in display configuration dialogs.

Create a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-disable-lvds.conf` and write there:

```
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "lvds monitor"
        Option  "ignore"        "true"
EndSection
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "onboard"
        Option  "Monitor-LVDS1" "lvds monitor"
EndSection
```

Comment: Correct answer imho, since apparently `video=LVDS-1:d` can be ignored by the X server.

Answer (score 3):

modify /etc/default/grub and add

```
video=LVDS-1:d video=VGA-1:e
```

:d disable :e enable.

For example mine is

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=LVDS-1:d video=VGA-1:e acpi=force elevator=noop i8042.noloop=1 usbhid.quirks=0xeef:0x1:0x40"acpi=force elevator=noop i8042.noloop=1 usbhid.quirks=0xeef:0x1:0x40"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Although this *should* work, it didn't in combination with GDM3. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Halox answer didn't fix the issue, as GDM3 configures the X server on it's own and re-enables the disabled monitor (silly).

After [reading the docs](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/3.6/configuration.html.en) I added `xrandr --output LVDS1 --off` at the top of `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` and finally got it to work.